# compiling linux 0.0.1 => error: ‘asm’ operand has impossible constraints __asm__("cld\n"

Tags: c, linux, compilation

I'm trying to compile linux kernel 0.0.1 from source code on my 64 bit intel machine.
Only to fill in the boot and main I had to modify all makefiles to get a 32-bit compilation.

So, this is the output of make:

```
In file included from traps.c:7:0:
../include/string.h:128:22: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘strchr’
 extern inline char * strchr(const char * s,char c)
                      ^
../include/string.h:145:22: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘strrchr’
 extern inline char * strrchr(const char * s,char c)
                      ^
../include/string.h:379:22: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘memchr’
 extern inline void * memchr(const void * cs,char c,int count)
                      ^
../include/string.h:395:22: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘memset’
 extern inline void * memset(void * s,char c,int count)
                      ^
In file included from traps.c:11:0:
../include/linux/kernel.h:5:1: warning: function return types not compatible due to ‘volatile’
 volatile void panic(const char * str);
 ^
../include/linux/kernel.h:5:1: warning: function return types not compatible due to ‘volatile’
../include/linux/kernel.h:5:1: warning: function return types not compatible due to ‘volatile’
In file included from traps.c:7:0:
../include/string.h: In function ‘strcpy’:
../include/string.h:29:1: error: ‘asm’ operand has impossible constraints
 __asm__("cld\n"
 ^
Makefile:24: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "traps.o" non riuscito
```

The portion of code of string.h is the following:

```
extern inline char * strcpy(char * dest,const char *src)
{
__asm__("cld\n"
    "1:\tlodsb\n\t"
    "stosb\n\t"
    "testb %%al,%%al\n\t"
    "jne 1b"
    ::"S" (src),"D" (dest):"si","di","ax");
return dest;
}
```

I don't know why the original code doesn't compile.
Until now I successfully compiled: boot and init subdir.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that the *register clobber list* overlaps with the inputs.

That is, the `"S"`  stands for register `esi` while `"D"` stands for register `edi`; but then the clobber list contains `"si"` and `"di"` that are the lower 16 bit pieces of those registers. Maybe old GCC versions ignored that, but newer ones do not allow overlaps.

From the [docs here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Clobbers):

> Clobber descriptions may not in any way overlap with an input or output operand.

Solution, just remove them from the list:

```
...
::"S" (src),"D" (dest) :"ax", "cc");
```

BTW, I also added the clobber to `"cc"` because that assembly modifies the `e` flag.

Comment: Thanks, it works with this example, but now the error is moved forward in the next function, here is used one more register. extern inline char * strncpy(char * dest,const char *src,int count)
{
__asm__("cld\n"
 "1:\tdecl %2\n\t"
 "js 2f\n\t"
 "lodsb\n\t"
 "stosb\n\t"
 "testb %%al,%%al\n\t"
 "jne 1b\n\t"
 "rep\n\t"
 "stosb\n"
 "2:"
 ::"S" (src),"D" (dest),"c" (count):"si","di","ax","cx");
return dest;
}

Comment: @JoAccount: Same thing. The clobber list should be just `:"ax", "cc"`. The "cx" overlaps with `"c"` that stands for register `ecx`.